# WiFi router restrict usage time per session

Tags: wireless-networking, router, proxy-server

I am trying to configure my WiFi router to restrict users to a session time of 30 min. I was reading through my router configuration booklet but could not find anything worthwile. It would be great if somebody can point me in a direction. Also is there a way to redirect users to a particular web page as they start their browsing session.

Router : DSL-2750U WIRELESS N ADSL2+ 4-PORT WI-FI ROUTER

http://www.dlink.co.in/products/?pid=452

Please recommend a different version of router/process if this is not good.

Thanks

Comment: Without details on the router brand and model you won't get much feedback...

Answer (score 1):

Restricting user session length isn't possible with your router (time-based is possible though). You'll have more luck installing third-party router firmware, such as DD-WRT and setting up [Chillispot](http://www.chillispot.org/).

Your router doesn't support DD-WRT, so you might want to replace it. Check their [compatibility database](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/support/router-database) first when you do decide on purchasing one.

Answer (score 1):

You can restrict the time certain *machines* may spend online, check page 55 of the manual:
ftp://support.dlink.co.in/broadband/DSL-2750U/manual/DSL-2750U_C1_Manual_IN_1.00.pdf

> To configure for MAC address blocking, enter the username into the
>   Username field, click Browser’s MAC Address to have MAC address of
>   the LAN device, or click Other MAC Address and enter a MAC address
>   manually. Tick the checkboxes for the desired individual days of the week
>   and enter desired Start Blocking Time and End Blocking Time.
>   Click the Save/Apply button to save the configuration